# onunload doesn't work when page is closing, for safari

Tags: html, onunload

```
<body onunload="notReady()">
<script >
    function notReady(){
      alert("closing")
    }
</script>
</body>
```

it works only when refreshing the page or clink some link on the page and the page is actually unloading, but not when it's closing.

why ? and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be work,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "closing!";
};
```

Comment: wait, you solution works even in safari , perfect. thanks! BTW, how did you find it out?